# Magento2 display custom Block after product Name on Product Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

In my custom Block I am trying this code:
which is not working:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
        name="product.view.extra"
        template="Ced_CsMarketplace::vendor.phtml" after="product.info.name">
         </block>
 </referenceBlock>
```

but when I am trying:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.price">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
        name="product.view.extra"
        template="Ced_CsMarketplace::vendor.phtml" before="-">
         </block>
 </referenceBlock>
```

It is working fine.

How I can show the block below Product Name and before product review.

I tried many alternative, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making use of the move element like this:

```
<move element="product.view.extra" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title"/>
```

Comment: Yes. If I try that it goes before the product name, I want it after product name.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is the right way to achieve that, but I am able to achieve what I was looking for with the below code:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.price">
 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
    name="product.view.extra"
    template="Ced_CsMarketplace::vendor.phtml" before="-">
   </block>
</referenceBlock>
<move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.price" before="-"/>
<move element="product.view.extra" destination="product.info.price" before="-"/>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to move after product name

```
<move element="custom.block" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" />
```

Comment: No that didn't work, I already mentioned as comment in other answer.